# Ativar Campo Select com Javascript

Tags: javascript

Caros,

Tenho um input text que vai receber uma data, e após o preenchimento deste campo, preciso que os combo selects sejam ativados. Por padrão, eles são desabilitados.

```
if (document.getElementById("payment").value.length > 0){
    document.getElementById('campo1').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('campo2').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('campo3').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('campo4').disabled = false;
} else {
    document.getElementById('campo1').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('campo2').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('campo3').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('campo4').disabled = true;
}
```

A pagina carrega com os inputs desabilitados, porem quando seto uma data no input (payment), os combos selects permanecem desabilitados. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Grato.

Comment: pode usa jquery?

Comment: claro @Jasar, pode sim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

entao vai ficar algo parecido com isso aqui

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#payment").keyup(function(){
       if($(this).val()) {
          $("#campo1").prop('disabled', true);
          $("#campo2").prop('disabled', true);
          $("#campo3").prop('disabled', true);
          $("#campo4").prop('disabled', true);
       } else {
          $("#campo1").prop('disabled', false);
          $("#campo2").prop('disabled', false);
          $("#campo3").prop('disabled', false);
          $("#campo4").prop('disabled', false);
       }
    });
});
```

pronto isso já deve bastar , se faltou algo m avise.

segue link do fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/joqs83mg/

Comment: Boa Jasar, mas os combos selects permanecem desativados assim que preencho o campo (payment)

Comment: vo cria um fiddle pera ai

Comment: pronto ta no fiddle

Comment: Funcionou Jasar. Grato pela ajuda.

Comment: legau, abraços ate mais

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready( function() {


  $("#payment").change( function() {
    
      var value = $("#payment").val();
    
          if (value == "") {
      $(".campo").removeAttr("disabled");
      }
    else {
      $(".campo").attr("disabled", "true");
      }
    
    });
  
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<input id="payment" type="text">

    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input class="campo" type="checkbox" value="">1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input class="campo" type="checkbox" value="">2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input class="campo" type="checkbox" value="">3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input class="campo" type="checkbox" value="">4</label>
    </div>
```

Fiz este código para você, não sei se é bem assim que você quer, mas tá ai! Basta dar o executar e testar!

Comment: Grato Sampaio!!! Testei e travou meu select. Não sei se tem diferença de checkbox para select. Mesmo assim, grato pelo tempo e interesse em meu ajudar.

Comment: pera, era um select, daqueles dropbox?

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: clicava em Executar para saber kkkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: Não entendi rss